# What is the limit on the number of array elements that can be passed to a MongoDB '$in' operator in a query?

Tags: mongodb, database

How many elements can `array` contain in the following query?

```
db.collection.find({field: {$in: array}});
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's however many you can fit in 16MB (i.e. I think maximum query size is the same as maximum document size). I don't have time to find a source for this now as I'm on my way out the door. If this question is still unanswered when I get back I'll try to find a source for this detail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Limit for *$in*(and any query) same as limit for document. Currently it's 16 mbs. [Here is](http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/28ae76e5ad5fcfb5?pli=1) related thread Google groups.

Comment: Have you seen any mention of this in the official docs? Seems like something they'd want to document.